# App Engine identifier. Key vs Id

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

To identify my JDO objects in Google App Engine I use the `Key` type. It works fine but when I need to pass this through urls it gets sort of long.

For example: `http://mysite.com/user/aghtaWx1LWFwcHIZCxIGTXlVc2VyGAMMCxIHTXlJbWFnZRgHDA`

When viewing my entities in my admin viewer I can see that the data-store also sets an "id" for my entity object, which seems to be an incremental numeric value, which is quite short compared to the Key string. Can I use this to grab information on my object? How do I do this? I tried using `getObjectbyId()` with the id instead of the key... it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code you used to try to get by id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Whenever you need to get the ID you can use the following method call. Assume you are using an object of the entity class `User` named `user`: `user.getKey().getId()`. The id is of type `long`. See the [JavaDoc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key.html) of `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key` for more information.

Whenever you have the ID you can build the `Key` from it and then simply query for the object.

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("User", id);
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
User user = datastore.get(key);
```

Comment: The `id` is actually a string, and it's the value that is visible in the data-store under the `ID/Name` column. Using your code with that doesn't work. I get something like: `Could not retrieve entity of kind User with key User("50")`

Comment: What you see there is the decoded entity key. If you haven't done so you have to parse the ID parameter String in your controller code (e.g. Servlet). Something like this would work in a Servlet: `Long.parseLong(httpServletRequest.getParameter("id")`. Do you see an entity with ID 50 in the datastore viewer?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You have to use a String (name of entity kind) when creating the key. Corrected the code above.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define the id in your Entity as a primary key:

```
private class MyObject implements Serializable{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

Then you can try this:

```
long id = someObject.getId();

MyObject mo = getPM().getObjectById(MyObject.class, id);
```

Comment: As stated in my question I'm using the type "Key" instead of "Long" for my key.